# ¿Ejecutar al inicio un script desarrollado con nodejs en ubuntu server 16?

Tags: nodejs, ubuntu, amazon-rds

Hola tengo un backend en amazon aws. Desarrollado con nodejs, y es necesario ejecutar ese script en lo que se inicie el sistema. Como podría hacer eso?

Comment: No esta muy claro lo que preguntas, ¿quieres que cuando la VM se bootea se ejecute cierto script?

Comment: Si. Que al iniciar la VM se ejecute una app desarrollada con nodejs

Comment: Disculpa no tengo tiempo de responder ahora, revisa esto http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/

Comment: La utilice pero al hacer un reboot, no inicio el servicio.

Comment: quiza hiciste algo mal, por que no agregas en la pregunta los pasos que seguiste para partir de esa base.

Comment: Saludos pude resolverlo con pm2 Gracias

Comment: Excelente, no es olvides compartir tu solución. Salu2

Answer (score 1):

El paquete [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) es simplemente excelente. Tiene muchos comandos que puedes usar para obtener información o para realizar acciones a más bajo nivel.

`pm2` lo que hace es primero detectar [init.d](https://www.linuxtotal.com.mx/index.php?cont=info_admon_003). En éste directorio, en sistemas UNIX, están muchos scripts para controlar servicios del sistema, por lo que, éstos scripts reconocen comandos como *start*, *stop*, entre otros.

El comando`app` empaqueta la aplicación Node.js como un demonio (ésto lo puedes ver en los logs), gerando un PUID y todo lo necesario para poder gestionarse. Puedes ver cómo lo hace leyendo [el código fuente](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/blob/master/lib/Daemon.js).

```
pm2 start app.js // app.js es el entry point de la aplicación
```

Hay más opciones como [node-startup](https://github.com/chovy/node-startup) o hacerlo directamente creando un archivo de configuración en *etc/init*, pero si estás en producción, `pm2` es lo más recomendado.